# Why is hibernate not reading updates made within a Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have an application with Spring and Hibernate and a scenario similar like this.

```
class Sheet{
   Set<Entry> entries;
}

class Entry{
   Sheet belongsTo;
   String name;
}


class Service{
  @Autowired GenericDao dao;

  @Transactional(readOnly=false)
  private void doSomething(){
     Sheet s1 = new Sheet();
     dao.create(s1);

     Entry a = new Entry();
     a.setSheet(s1);
     dao.create(a);

     // Now I expect, that when updating my sheet there should be my Entry 'a' in the PersistentBag of the sheet
     dao.refresh(s1)
     s1.getEntries(); // <-- entry 'a' is not in the List.
  }
}
```

Of course there are setters/getters and the necessary annotations in the classes.

If I call `s1.getEntries()` in another service-call (with a new transaction, and after the transaction above was committed) I have the entry `'a'` in the List of my Sheet.

I'm wondering, why I can't read the changes I made in the transaction WITHIN the same transaction.
Why is the PersistentBag not getting updated?

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5 and Spring 4.0.5.

Comment: Does the create method commits the changes made? If not, I would suggest a forced commit so that the changes take effect.

Comment: No, it doesn't and it shouldn't! The whole ServiceMethod `doSomething()` runs - and should run - in one transaction!

Comment: YOu should be managing both sides of the dependencies. Hibernate isn't going to update in memory objects on the fly. If you have a bi-directional relation ship make sure you properly set both of them.

Comment: That's a pitty! SInce my example is not that easy than stated above. There are many more relations which I would have to set. This is a quite complicated business-service, having approx. 10 updates and a few inserts into the database. Is there really no other possibility?